# Android Service for socket

Tags: android, sockets, service, networkonmainthread

I'm trying to use a service to connect to a server with a socket. But for some reasons, it cannot connect to it returning a NetworkOnMainThreadException at this line

```
socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT);
```

I have already added Permission and the service in the manifest.

```
public class SocketService extends Service{

    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private Socket socket = null;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;



    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        SocketService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return SocketService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;
    }

     /** method for clients */
    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public InputStream getDataInputStream() throws IOException {
        return socket.getInputStream();
    }

    public OutputStream getDataOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return socket.getOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";
        int SERVERPORT = 8080;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT);
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Erreur","Connexion impossible !");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String sendMessage(String message) {     
        String response = "";
        try {
            out.writeBytes(message + "\n");
            out.flush();
            response = this.in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Is it the good way to do it using a Bound service ? 
I would like to use this service in many activities, and in the Android documentation, it says that using a Bound service is good for that.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put the code where the connection is made in other thread(try to use asyncTask)

read a documentation 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 0):

Doing network stuff in a Service is a good idea when network requests are not tied to any particular activity.  But whether the Service is running in the same process or a different one, its lifecycle methods are still called on its "main" thread.  Spare yourself the hassle of using AsyncTasks directly and use a library that encapsulates them like android-async-http.